# Interval estimation of mean of future predicted values

Tags: r, bayesian, rstan

I have a Bayesian code for estimating a model (a bit complicated model) in RStan. After estimating the model I took 500 samples of parameter sets from the posterior distribution to simulate data from the model for future (next 1 month). Finally I took the means of the predicted values (500 predicted values for each time point) and then compared them with the actual observations (with a plot).

My question is- how can I calculate the intervals of these means of the predicted values?

Example: After drawing the sample of parameters from the posterior distribution, I simulated variables X1,X2,....X30 from the model using these parameters:

```
X1= (33,25,10,19,25)
X2= (11,10,15,13.5,17)
.......

X30= (40,33.3,50,29,45.1)
```

Now I find mean(X1); mean(X2);....mean(X30) and plot them against time. I want to find intervals for these means.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "calculate the intervals of these means of the predicted values" ... what kind of interval do you want? Also, having some minimal example makes the issue concrete. I would suggest creating a toy example where you can post a small dataset and code.

Comment: @ssp3nc3r hi, I want some kind of "prediction interval" for the mean of the predicted values. I am providing a toy example above.

Comment: If you mean credible interval, and X1, for example, represents multiple posterior draws, then you can just do something like, `quantile(X1, probs = c(.1, .9))`, which provides the middle 80 percent of the draws.

Answer (score 3):

Example posterior draws for each X1 ... X30:

```
m <- matrix(data = rep(rnorm(500, 0, 1), 30), nrow = 500, ncol = 30, byrow = FALSE)
colnames(m) <- paste0("X", 1:30)
```

Get credible interval of these draws:

```
ci <- apply(m, 2, quantile, probs = c(0.1, 0.9))
colnames(ci) <- paste0("X", 1:30)
```